# Exporting a KendoGrid via PDF and additional template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendogrid with working PDF export.
Now I want to add a header to each exported page (e.g. Customer Name and Number). I tried to do it like the provided demo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/UfILe), but I don't see the Text or pagenumbers. It does, however, add the margins to the document.

**The Template:**

```
<script id="page-template-pdf" type="x/kendo-template">
<div class="page-template-pdf">
    <div class="header-pdf">
        Customer: {{cust.id}}
    </div>
    <div class="footer-pdf">
        <div style="float: right">Page #: pageNum # of #: totalPages #</div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.page-template-pdf {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

    .page-template-pdf .header-pdf {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        right: 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: orangered;
    }

    .page-template-pdf .footer-pdf {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        right: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

**Grid Definition inside my controller:**

```
...            
toolbar: [
                { name: "pdf", text: "PDF Export" },
                { name: "excel", text: "Excel Export" },
                { template: kendo.template($("#laGridFilterTemplate").html()) }
            ],
            pdf: {
                allPages: true,
                landscape: true,
                paperSize: ["1573pt", "672pt"],
                margin: { top: "3cm", right: "0cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "0cm" },
                template: kendo.template($("#page-template-pdf").html())
            }, ...
```

Comment: Did you mean to give your div class and script id the same name -"page-template"?

Comment: yes because telerik did it too. It doesn't matter if I change it to something else, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would hope that you would have found a solution since 5 months ago, however I have been struggling with this most of today and the fix for me was to add a standard papersize.

**Grid PDF Definition**

```
pdf: {
        allPages: true,
        avoidLinks: true,
        repeatHeaders: true,
        template: kendo.template($("#page-template").html()),
        scale: 0.8,
        margin: { top: "3cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "1cm" },
        paperSize: "A4",
        landscape: true
    }
```

Hopefully may help someone else who has been scouring SO for Kendo guidance.

Comment: Thanks. You are right that setting the paperSize helps in general, but it did nothing for my scenario. Eventually our problem "solved" itself by installing the newest Kendo version.

Comment: It's incredible how many times I see the answer to Kendo related questions, _Please install the latest version of Kendo_

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. But it only works if what you want to pass to the template is part of the page's URL.  For me, the last element in the url after the last "/" was what I wanted in my pdf export header.  I did this for the header div inside the kendo-template and it worked for me:

```
<div class="header">
    # var ar = window.location.href.split('/'); #
    #: ar[ar.length - 1] #
</div>
```